# IOS 7.1: Not able to detect retina device in ipad2

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I know,

We can detect retina device by either of the following methosds:

```
BOOL isRetina;
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2){
    isRetina = YES;
} else {
    isRetina = NO;
}
```

or

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)]){ 
        NSLog(@"scale = %f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] > 1.0) {
            NSLog(@"Retina Display iPad3");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Non Retina Display iPad 1/2");
        }
}
```

But when i run this code into my ipad 2 which has ios 7.1, i am getting , it is non-retina device and when i run this code into ipad retina device's simulator it is working perfectly there.

Any guideline?

Comment: ipad2 is non retina device.

Comment: Ramdy and LearnCocos2D are right. Even your own code says: `NSLog(@"Non Retina Display iPad 1/2");`

Comment: i think resolution is 2048*1536, right?

Comment: @Renaissance, No, it is 1024x768. iPad 3 was the first iPad to have a retina display.

Answer (score 3):

The code is correct. The iPad 2 does not have a Retina screen.

Comment: yes, winsize and winsizeinpixel both are giving same-1024*768. But when we make asset for cocos2d game and if we are supporting ipad2 then we make it to size 2048*1536. right?

Comment: You need to make the assets this size for the Retina iPads (iPad 3 and newer). For iPad 2 you either have to provide -ipad resolution images adjusted to the 1024x768 pixel resolution, or design your game so that the iPhone HD assets (1136x640 pixel) also fit the iPad 2 screen size (slightly less wide, slightly higher). If you do not support iPhone devices, you have to provide a separate set of assets for the non-Retina iPads (iPad 1 & 2) or just don't support the non-Retina iPads (easier, smaller bundle size).